# Do we have CLI support for ink! smart contract deployment on configured test-net?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, cli

I want to deploy my contract on Rococo contract test net. Apart from *polkadot.js/apps*, do we have any other way to upload and then instantiate the contract?

My goal is to create a script for the contract deployment for the provided network configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use [`cargo contract`](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract) to interact with a chain. It supports the full range of interactions: `upload`, `instantiate`, `call`. Use the `--url` option to point it to your testnet.

Comment: if it is possible, can you share automated script for upload and instantiate?

Answer (score 2):

[Swanky suite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@astar-network/swanky-cli) does exactly that. You can scaffold, compile, and deploy the contract to the network you specify.
Still under heavy development, but all of the above is usable already.

(I am on the team that's working on it)

Comment: Thanks!! codespool